# SwiftUI / Navigation problem: navigation stack - how to delete an "intermediate" view? (list->new->detail)

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

Trying to figure out how to hack the SwiftUI navigation stack to ignore an intermediate view. Targeting iOS 15. Have a SwiftUI views for:

1. List of Items ("home")
2. Item Details ("details")
3. New Item Config ("new")

To create a new Item, user has to navigate to "new" view, and is then sent to "details" for the just created item.  Clicking on the "back" caret from "details" should always return to "home" list.

Effectively, I want to delete the "new" view from the navigation stack when passing through it.

The only solution I've come up with is to pass back to "home" an indicator that forces immediate nav to "details" of the new item, but I'm hoping for a cleaner solution...

Comment: Are you talking about `NavigationView{}` or `NavigationStack{}` container here?. Also, include some reproducible code, I can't imagine your code.